# Hide CSS dropdown menu with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dropdown that works with CSS. I want it to disappear when an item in the dropdown is clicked, but still function correctly after words.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
$("span").click(function(){
 $(this).parent().hide();
 $("#text").html("Try hovering over it again. Now it's broken, because the display attribute was set for the element.");
});
```

```css
.dropDownContainer{
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropDown{
  display: none;
  padding-left: 6px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white; 
  position: absolute;
}

.dropDownContainer:hover .dropDown {
  display: block;
}
span{
  cursor:pointer;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropDownContainer">
  hover over this
  <div class="dropDown">
    this is the dropdown<br><br>
  
    click <span>this</span> to close drop down.
    <br><br>
    It doesn't work.
  </div>
</div>
<div id="text">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a timeout to remove the display none right after you hide. so the cursor wont be positioned in a way it will automatically reopen (on hover this) so its fine.

```
$("span").off().click(function(){
    var dropdown = $(this).parent();
    dropdown.hide();
    setTimeout(function(){dropdown.removeAttr('style');}, 300);
    $("#text").html("Try hovering over it again. Now it's broken, because the display attribute was set for the element.");
});
```

Comment: Works great. What is the function of the "off()"?

Comment: Oops i forgot to remove the unneeded `off()` before publish answer. Actually for my trial - directly on your code, i opened the JS console and override your event, that is why I `off()` it first. It means unbound all events binded to this element!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code a bit see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dLcLoggx/1/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropDownContainer">
  <span class="trigger">hover over this</span>
  <div class="dropDown">
    this is the dropdown<br><br>

    click <span>this</span> to close drop down.
    <br><br>
    It doesn't work.
  </div>
</div>
<div id="text">

</div>

.dropDownContainer{
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropDown{
  display: none;
  padding-left: 6px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white; 
  position: absolute;
}


span{
  cursor:pointer;
  color: red;
}

$(".dropDown span").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
});

$("span.trigger").hover(function(){
    $('.dropDown').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have any event handler to hover and open it first. If you close or open something with CSS, you should use CSS to open or close it as well, same goes for JS/jQ, otherwise they may conflict.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(".dropDownHeader").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(".dropDownContainer").show();
  $("kbd").on("click", function() {
    $('.dropDownContainer').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropDownContainer {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 6px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropDownHeader:hover .dropDown {
  display: block;
}
kbd {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="dropDownHeader">
  <h3>Hover over this</h3>
</header>
<div class="dropDownContainer">
  <p>This is the dropdown</p>

  <p>Click <kbd>this</kbd> to close drop down.</p>

  <p>It doesn't work.</p>
</div>

<article id="text">

</article>
```